# Ember-simple-auth: Authenticating from URL

Tags: ember.js, ember-simple-auth

I have a requirement that I can append `?auth_token=x` to any URL in my app and it will restore the session as if you had a cookie or the details were stored in local storage.

I've tried every manner I can think of to implement this over the last few hours but I'm not getting anywhere. Is this possible? Where should I be looking to add such functionality?

Comment: Did u try http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/query-params/

Comment: Yes, that seems to work fine once everything is initialized and transitions are underway/finished. In my case I need to handle the authentication earlier than that so I have my own query param handling which works fine. The problem is where in ember-simple-auth I can trigger the authentication before it tries to redirect to the login page.

Comment: If you use Ember.SimpleAuth you already have the session state stored in localStorage. I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to achieve here. If you have a valid session in localStorage the session will be restored automatically. When you want to pass the token to the server in the URL instead of the `Authorization` header you can implement a custom authorizer (see here: https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth#implementing-a-custom-authorizer).

Comment: I have a use case where there is no session already stored but user's need to be able to click a link or be passed through auth automatically from an external service and have a session created for them. I managed to achieve this, I'll post my code up in an answer shortly

Comment: @marcoow I've posted up my code, if you have a moment to take a look perhaps there is a better entry point available in Ember.SimpleAuth than what I have used?

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering my own question here as I managed to find a solution, although how correct it is I'm not sure!

application.js:

```
// Really simple query parameter access
(function($) {
  $.QueryString = (function(a) {
    if (a == "") return {};
    var b = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i)
    {
      var p=a[i].split('=');
      if (p.length != 2) continue;
      b[p[0]] = decodeURIComponent(p[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
    }
    return b;
  })(window.location.search.substr(1).split('&'))
})(jQuery);
```

initializers/authentication.js.coffee:

```
LocalStorageWithURLAuth = Ember.SimpleAuth.Stores.LocalStorage.extend
  init: ->
    if $.QueryString['auth_token']
      auth_token = $.QueryString['auth_token']
      Ember.$.ajax(
        async: false
        url: '/users/sign_in'
        type: 'POST'
        data: { auth_token: auth_token }
        dataType: 'json'
      ).then (data) =>
        @persist
          auth_token: data.auth_token
          auth_email: data.auth_email
          user_id: data.user_id
          authenticatorFactory: 'authenticator:devise'
        @_super()
      , (error) =>
        @_super()
    else
      @_super()

Ember.Application.initializer
  name: 'authentication'
  initialize: (container, application) ->
    Ember.SimpleAuth.Session.reopen
      user: (->
        userId = @get 'user_id'
        if !Ember.isEmpty userId
          container.lookup('store:main').find 'user', userId
      ).property('user_id')

    container.register 'session-store:local-storage-url', LocalStorageWithURLAuth

    Ember.SimpleAuth.setup container, application,
      storeFactory: 'session-store:local-storage-url'
      authenticatorFactory: 'authenticator:devise'
      authorizerFactory: 'authorizer:devise'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what you're doing. It seems like you're restoring the session from an auth token in the query string? That's actually what the authenticator's `restore` method is for (see docs here: http://ember-simple-auth.simplabs.com/ember-simple-auth-devise-api-docs.html#Ember-SimpleAuth-Authenticators-Devise-restore). Also when the application starts isn't the query string empty?

Comment: The query string has a one-time auth_token param in it that is used to create a new session. I spent a lot of time trying to get the `restore` method to work as I thought that was the best place for it but I only have part of the properties needed to restore a session and running an additional ajax request in that method proved tricky.  The query string is present when the application starts as it's used to authenticate a user directly from a link in an e-mail or as part of a redirect chain in an external service.

Comment: Now that I think about it I think the issue I had with the `restore`  method was that it wasn't actually being called when I needed so any code I put in there was useless. The approach I ended up with pre-populates LocalStorage so that the restore function runs and can restore the session.

Comment: The `restore` method is called when the application launches and whenever anything changes in the store.